# Google Colaboratory disk

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, google-colaboratory

My Google Drive storage is 2TB and I have only used 44GB, but the disk in Google Colabarotary is stuck at 60GB and when I run my piece of code in Google Colaboratory notebook that works with a video dataset and is supposed to extract each video to its frames, after some time of running, it stops and gives a message that there is not enough storage to write on the disk. I know it is not possible, because the size of the entire dataset as frames would be 288GB and I have empty storage way more than that.

I would appreciate it if someone tells me how I can extend the Google Colaboratory disk and make it to actually see the disk storage in my Google Drive, even though I have mounted it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Colab has a [Pro version](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) that doubles the size of local disks. That won't quite bring you to 288G presently, however.